# How to generate random passwords with options in Java?

Tags: java, random

I know there is `nextInt`, `nextDouble`, etc for numbers and even a `nextBoolean` for `true` or `false`, but I haven't found anything for `Strings` with the following:

- Ability to create a minimum / maximum or even specific longitudes. For instance, create a random string between 6 or 8 characters, or create a random string with 12 characters
- Ability to specify a schema. For instance, only numbers, only letters, only uppercase letters, only special signs like `!@#$%^&`, etc

Basically, what I'm trying to create, is a [Crunch tool](http://tools.kali.org/password-attacks/crunch), a pen testing tool able to generate random passwords, but for Java, using only the JDK (it can be JDK8, but I'm not interested in third party libraries), making use of the maximum amount of available built in tools in my code, just for the sake of not reinventing the wheel. I would like to know the available methods before starting to code.

I'm not looking for something able to give me everything I want. I just would like to know the function to call to retrieve, for instance, a random char, or a random uppercase char, etc. I have no issues gluing everything together.

I'm looking for OOTB tools to help me accomplish this. This also implies, the ability to ask Java for specifics characters, like only letters, only signs, only upper case letters, only numbers, etc. I know I can play with bytes and converting them to chars, but perhaps there is an already efficient and built in functionality to make use of.

DimaSan was able to provide part of what I was looking for. I will be able to use a mix of his code and the `Character` comparison methods, like:

```
isDigit
isLetter
isLetterOrDigit
isLowerCase
isUpperCase
isSpaceChar
isDefined
```

I took those methods from the Oracle docs, where I was able to find a good example:

> Developers who aren't used to writing global software might determine
>   a character's properties by comparing it with character constants. For
>   instance, they might write code like this:

```
char ch;
//...

// This code is WRONG!

// check if ch is a letter
if ((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'))
    // ...

// check if ch is a digit
if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
    // ...

// check if ch is a whitespace
if ((ch == ' ') || (ch =='\n') || (ch == '\t'))
    // ...
```

> The preceding code is wrong because it works only with English and a
>   few other languages. To internationalize the previous example, replace
>   it with the following statements:

```
char ch;
// ...

// This code is OK!

if (Character.isLetter(ch))
    // ...

if (Character.isDigit(ch))
    // ...

if (Character.isSpaceChar(ch))
    // ...
```

Gluing everything together I will be able to make what I was asking for. Thank you.

Comment: No. That's for you to code. That's what programming is: Writing the code to get what you need.

Comment: I think I was able to explain why this is not a duplicate, please let me know if this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no OOTB random string generator in Java.

But I'd like to recommend you a generator I wrote and use in my project:

```
public class RandomGenerator {
    private static final String characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    public static String generateRandom(int length) {
        if (length <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("String length must be a positive integer");
        }

        Random random = new SecureRandom();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            sb.append(characters.charAt(random.nextInt(characters.length())));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

- in `characters` string you can put any characters you want to be included
- `int length` parameter is the length of generated random string.

Comment: This is pretty nice and short. Do you know if Java provides a way to replace your "characters" variable with some sort of built in schematics for just numbers, alphabet, signs, etc?

Comment: @facundop unfortunately I didn't find the solution you are talking about. When I need numbers I just replace it with `0123456789` and so on. Btw if you'll find something please let me know as well, thanks.

Comment: I edited my original question. I will make use of the Character API for now to filter out good candidates. Thanks!

Comment: @facundop And how do you like the idea to pass a set of using characters as a parameter to the method to make it more generic: `generateRandom(String characters, int length)`?

Comment: I like the idea. I'm still thinking about creating a properties file tho. I was hoping to use the output of this little app as the input for other console based app

Comment: I think this is very nice idea to use this little generator (of passwords, some numbers) for other apps. I use it for generating transfer numbers to send to users' mobile phones. It might also be a service. Btw I haven't any idea why people downvoted this useful question.