# Randomly generated number of X's

Tags: java, loops, random, range

I need a program to randomly generate a number, and then out put that number of x's, on there own line, until it outputs a line of 16 x's, and then it will stop. So far my program generates a number but never stops outputting. I'm sure this is my error but not sure what needs to change. Here is my code at this moment.

```
import java.util.Random;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    toBinary();
    randomX();
}

public static void randomX()
{
    Random num = new Random();
    int ran = num.nextInt(16+1);
    int xs = ran;

    while(xs <= 16)
    {
        System.out.print("x");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185629/how-to-generate-random-passwords-with-options-in-java/40185656#40185656) to your problem. Btw it is much broader as could generate any character sequence of any length, and very easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

To approach this, think of the loops you might need.
You need to print x a certain number of times, that's a loop. I also introduce a variable to keep track of this printing.
You need to keep printing until you hit 16. That's another loop.

```
public static void randomX(){
  Random num = new Random();
  int xs = 0;
  //This loop keeps going until you reach 16
  while(xs <= 16){
    xs = num.nextInt(16+1);
    int x = 0;
    //This loop keeps going until you've printed enough x's
    while (x < xs)
    {
      System.out.print("x");
      x++;
    }

    System.out.println("")
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @DimaSan added a bit of an explanation. And added the newline that I'd forgotten.

Comment: @Jean-Bernard Pellerin Okay so I reformatted the code to be like this, and even copied this to see if it would work, but after compiling there is no output from the code.

Comment: @DPabst That's because it's being initialized to 17, so it never enters the outer loop.

Comment: @pjs Doh! nice catch. I changed my logic and forgot to go back for that one.

Comment: @Jean-BernardPellerin We've all been there!  ;)

Comment: While(xs <= 16) should be != or it never stops even though its the right format. Thanks guys. You've been a big help.

Comment: @DPabst My very strong advice is stick with inequality tests for loops, as suggested in the answer I provided.  Tests of `==` or `!=` are fragile if the code gets modified in such a way that it steps over the value being tested.

Answer (score 2):

Your version has a number of small issues.  Here's a suggested set of revisions.

```
// create your random object outside the method, otherwise
// you're instantiating a new one each time.  In the long run
// this can cause awkward behaviors due to initialization.
public static Random num = new Random();

public static void randomX(){
   int ran;
   do {
      ran = 1 + num.nextInt(16); // move the +1 outside unless you actually want 0's
      int counter = 0;
      while(counter++ < ran) {
        System.out.print("x");
      }
      System.out.println();  // add a newline after printing the x's in a row
   } while(ran < 16);
}
```

The biggest issue is that you need *two* loops, an outer one for generating new numbers and an inner one for printing the current number of x's.

A secondary problem was that your loop was checking for numbers <**=** 16.  All of your values are <= 16, so it was an infinite loop.

Additional suggestions found in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a auxiliary counter to manage the loop and increase it to exit the loop.

```
int i = 0;
while (i<xs){
    System.out.print("x");
    i++;
}
```

You can check more about java loops here:

[Tutorial about java while](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_while_loop.htm)